# Setting a new position of bitmap on canvas with deleting previuos one

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, position

I have this code:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ball, (canvas.getWidth()/2), 0, null);
```

and it draw bitmap on  screen but if i want to set  new position it draw  new one, how can i draw a new one and erase previous one. I'd like to set new position of bitmap on canvas.

Comment: Please use normal writing, not "wnt", "cn", etc.

Comment: my latter "a" seems not working fine

Comment: To redraw the Bitmap on new position, redraw the Canvas with a new color and draw the bitmap with newly specified coordinates. This is basically a copy/paste of your last 2 lines.

Comment: so if i want object to move with 60 fps i have to redraw the canvas with new color every 0.1 sec? or is there any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing color first will erease all then draw your Bitmap with new position.

Comment: lets say we have 4 Bitmaps and each of them is moving on his own direction, so i have to redraw all bitmaps when i draw color first.

Comment: Yes. Google for simple game loops.